# VanillaJS convert String to html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I convert my project from jquery to VanillaJS. During an ajax call I get an html response like this one:

```
"    <div class=\"row\" id=\"table-section\">\n...
```

With JQuery and $.ajax my answer is automatically formatted in valid html :

```
<div class="row" id="table-section">
```

I'm desperately looking for a way to do the same thing in pure JS, but I can't find it.
I did this :

```
                 fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            }
        }).then(response => {
            response.text().then(data => {
                var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/html");

                console.log(doc.body);
                document.getElementById('table-section').innerHTML = doc.body.innerHtml;
            })

        });
```

But of course it returns the original string instead of a valid html. How to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean it returns valid html? What is the jQuery code you are trying to replace exactly?

Comment: ` $.ajax({
                url: 'myurl',
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#table-section').append($(response));
                }
            });`

valid html is can be display by browser. With jquery it's work but in pure js it's look like à string with \n \'\...

Comment: That is valid HTML, inside a JavaScript string, with the appropriate characters escaped. Have you tried just `document.getElementById('table-section').innerHTML = data`?

Comment: of course, but it display html code  (<th> <tr> <td> ...)not the table interpreter

Comment: Oh wait, I try to change response.text to response.json and it's works